# Prove that in any set $A_\epsilon=(-\infty,-\epsilon]\cup[\epsilon, \infty)\subset \mathbb{R}$...

Tags: uniform-convergence

Prove that in any set $A_\epsilon=(-\infty,-\epsilon]\cup[\epsilon, \infty)\subset 
\mathbb{R}$, where $\epsilon>0$, the convergence of $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\:\: \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\stackrel{pw}{=}f(x)  = 
  \begin{cases}\begin{align}
    1 \quad&\text{ if }\; x\neq0, \\
    0 \quad&\text{ if }\; x=0 \\ 
  \end{align}\end{cases}$
is uniform.

Where $f_n(x)=\frac{nx^2}{nx^2+1}, x\in\mathbb{R}$

The first part of the question is to prove that the equation I listed is not uniform and I did that using Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem. It seems intuitive that when you don't include 0 as is the case here (because epsilon is arbitrarily small but not 0) that it should be convergent but I don't know how to prove. The section that we are in talks a fair bit about Lesbesgue and also mentions the Weierstrab M-Test (though I don't think that applies) and is about commuting limits with integrals and derivatives.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the integral above ?

Comment: @FardadPouran Nice catch, I have added it in now.

Comment: $$|f_n(x)-1|\leqslant\frac1{n\epsilon^2}\to0$$

Comment: @Did I'm not finding this in my book. Do explain?

Comment: Did you compute $|f_n(x)-1|$? What is the result you got?

Comment: @Did Looks to me like it's 0. It is true that 0 will always be smaller than the $\frac{1}{n\epsilon^2}$ but I don't see the relevance. :/

Comment: $|f_n(x)-1|=0$, you say? Hmmm...

Comment: @Did Are you saying that that is wrong? Perhaps you could provide the relevance of $|f_n(x)-1|$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22051/discussion-between-chriskinda-and-did).

Comment: "Let us continue this discussion in chat." No need to, let us rather follow my very first advice: did you compute $|f_n(x)-1|$, and what did you get?

Comment: @Did I'm guessing you don't agree with my 0 conclusion then. Here is my rational, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{nx^2}{nx^2+1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dn}(nx^2)}{\frac{d}{dn}(nx^2+1)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1$ so $|f_n(x)-1|=1-1=0$

Comment: Argh... Ever heard of the difference between value and limit?

Comment: @Did Sure, a value is just any number. A limit is what a function converges to. Correct?